# multiple properties in swagger json

Tags: json, api, swagger

I am developing an api with swagger and want in the successful response something like:

[image]
Code and subCode are under BankTransactionCode.

This is how I am trying to achieve this, by adding code and subCode as properties under BankTransactionCode

```
    "responses" : {
      "200" : {
        "description" : "response description",
        "schema" : {
          "type" : "object",
          "properties" : {
            "amount" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "maxLength" : 25
            },
            "accountIBAN" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "valueDate" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "format" : "date"
            },
            **"BankTransactionCode": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "code": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 60
                },
                "subCode": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 60
                }**
              }
            }
```

Unfortunately, something is not right, can anyone tell why?

Comment: Other than capitalization of property names (`code` should be `Code` and `subCode` should be `SubCode`) your spec is correct. What exactly problem do you have?

Comment: when testing I get the following error: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: {"header":{"audit":{"T24_time":115,"parse_time":1},"page_start":0,"page_token":"9ca70339-67cf-4fa6-bf82-db133692d483","total_size":0,"page_size":50},"body":}; line: 1, column: 158]

Comment: It's a problem with the request, not the response - the request is missing the value for `body`. What tool do you use to test the requests? Did you actually specify the value for `body`?